# Async cloudflare KV PUT request

Tags: javascript, async-await, cloudflare

I'm trying to use this fetch to then add some data into the KV on the .then how do I exactly structure this with the innermost function being async? At the moment I get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word`

This is the code:

```
fetch('https://www.uuidtools.com/api/generate/v4')
    .then (data => {
        await NAMESPACE.put(id, data)
    })
```

Comment: "*with the innermost function being async?*" - well, it isn't `async`, that's why you get the error.

Comment: Don't mix `.then()` syntax with `await` syntax. Start with `const data = await fetch('https://www.uuidtools.com/api/generate/v4');`, and mark the *outer* function as `async`.